# Define a variable inside a function

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I am wondering if it is possible to do like JavaScript, calling a variable from a function, something like:

```
function myFunction(variable){
// do some stuff here

}
```

Then we call it like:

```
myFunction('Hello World!');
```

So this is the way how to handle that:

```
convertSecs(){

seconds=$1

hours=$((seconds / 3600))
seconds=$((seconds % 3600))
minutes=$((seconds / 60))
seconds=$((seconds % 60))

echo "$hours hour(s) $minutes minute(s) $seconds second(s)"
}

convertSecs 3680
```

Thanks for your advice

Comment: "calling a variable from a function" doesn't make much sense - your function is just a stub, you haven't used the variable in any way, let alone call it (which would mean using the variable as a function). And your title doesn't really correspond to your body either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `bash` handles that differently.

Actually `bash` uses positional parameter(s) (arguments) instead of directly using the usual `function_name(input_var)` format.

Inside the function definition, use `$1` for first argument to the function, `$2` for second and so on. While referring the function, just tag along the parameters after the function name (maintain the desired sequence).

**Example:**

```
$ foo () { echo "This is $1" ;}
$ foo bar
This is bar

$ foo () { echo "First: $1; Second: $2" ;}
$ foo bar spam
First: bar; Second: spam
```

Comment: @AbuRayane You got it :)